# Múltiplas Galeria com LightGallery

Tags: javascript

Estou usando o plugin [LightGallery](https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightgallery.js/), na página tenho várias galerias, estou exibindo apenas uma imagem de cada galeria, para que ao haver o clique nesta imagem ela abra a sua respectiva galeria.

```
<img src="assets/images/lisboa/1.jpg" id="galeria_1" galeria_id="galeria_1">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#galeria_1').on('click', function(){

            var galeria_id = $(this).attr("galeria_id");

            $("#"+galeria_id).lightGallery({
                download: false,
                counter: false,
                hash: true,
                galleryId: galeria_id
            });
        });
    });
```

Simplesmente não acontece nada e nenhum erro no console.

Comment: O link que vc passou é da versão javascript puro, mas vc está usando o do [jquery](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/), certo?

Comment: Ao invés de aplicar o `lightGallery` comente no `click`, pq vc não faz um `.each` para todos os itens e aplica sempre, pelo que vi na documentação e [exemplos](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/demos/) quando clica no elemento abre a imagem.

Comment: preciso usa-lo com o clique em apenas um item, que nesse caso é uma imagem qualquer, ao clicar nela, ela deverá abrir a galeria correspondente ao seu atributo `galeria_id`

Comment: Então, mas ao executar `.lightGallery({})` dentro do click, ele vai configurar o elemento para ser a galeria e não abrir a galeria... por isso falei que vc deveria fazer isso para cada link q vai abrir uma galeria diferente. `.lightGallery({})` deve ser executado quando  dom estiver ok....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionei

```
<img src="assets/images/lisboa/1.jpg" class="galeria galeria_bt" galeria_id="galeria_1">

<div id="galeria_1" class="galeria" style="display:none">
    <div class="item1" data-src="assets/images/lisboa/2.jpg" data-sub-html="">
        <img class="" src="assets/images/lisboa/2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="" data-src="assets/images/lisboa/3.jpg" data-sub-html="">
        <img class="" src="assets/images/lisboa/3.jpg">
    </div>
</div>


$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".galeria").lightGallery({
        download: false,
        thumbnail:true
    });

    $('.galeria_bt').on('click', function(){
        var galeria_id = $(this).attr("galeria_id");
        $("#"+galeria_id+" div:first-child").trigger('click');
    });
});
```